# Rails can't map automatically "y" ending plural models, is it possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, mapping, models, pluralize

In my rails app, I added the model `TreeNursery`, then added in routes.rb `resources :tree_nurseries do...`.

The first problem that I've got is that when I added `has_many :tree_nurseries`  to the `Village` model, rails couldn't map it before I added `:class_name => 'TreeNursery'`.

After that, when I do `rake routes` I get `tree_nurseries_index` which is very weird for me.

Is there any clue for this ?